# Creating an empty set

Tags: python

I have some code which tots up a set of selected values. I would like to define an empty set and add to it, but `{}` keeps turning into a dictionary.  I have found if I populate the set with a dummy value I can use it, but it's not very elegant.  Can someone tell me the proper way to do this?  Thanks.

```
inversIndex = {'five': {1}, 'ten': {2}, 'twenty': {3},
               'two': {0, 1, 2}, 'eight': {2}, 'four': {1},
               'six': {1}, 'seven': {1}, 'three': {0, 2},
               'nine': {2}, 'twelve': {2}, 'zero': {0, 1, 3},
               'eleven': {2}, 'one': {0}}

query = ['four', 'two', 'three']

def orSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    b = [ inverseIndex[c] for c in query ]
    x = {'dummy'}
    for y in b:
        { x.add(z) for z in y }
    x.remove('dummy')
    return x

orSearch(inverseIndex, query)
```

> {0, 1, 2}

Comment: A `set`?  Just use `set()`.

Comment: Using a set comprehension only for its side effects?

Comment: Yeah, a very hacky newbie ;^)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can just construct a set:

```
>>> s = set()
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 9):

The "proper" way to do it:

```
myset = set()
```

The `{...}` notation cannot be used to initialize an empty set

Comment: Not true; curly braces can be used for nonempty set literals.

Answer (score 4):

A set literal is just **a tuple** of values in curly braces:

```
x = {2, 3, 5, 7}
```

So, you can create an empty set with **empty tuple** of values in curly braces:

```
x = {*()}
```

Still, just because you *can*, doesn't mean you *should*.

Unless it's an obfuscated programming, or a [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) where every character matters, I'd suggest an explicit `x = set()` instead.

[*"Explicit is better than implicit."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python)

Comment: `{*()}` could very easily be constant-folded (and therefore execute slightly faster), unlike `set()`; although as of Python 3.10, it isn’t yet.

Comment: <https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/77381>

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out - the way to get an empy `set` literal is via `set()`, however, if you re-wrote your code, you don't need to worry about this, eg (and using `set()`):

```
from operator import itemgetter
query = ['four', 'two', 'three']
result = set().union(*itemgetter(*query)(inversIndex))
# set([0, 1, 2])
```