# Create Empty Set in Python: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I would like to create an empty set in Python.

I tried `set1 = set()`
as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130374/empty-set-literal).

However I get the error:

```
set1 = set()
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

How can I create an empty set in Python?

Comment: You've assigned a `dict` object to the name `set` somewhere in your code. That is why `set()` is producing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `foo = set()` is the right way to declare empty set in both python 2 and python 3.

I guess you have a `set = {}` in the former lines.

You can try `print(type(set))` to check it.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error while not having any already declared foo before declaring with `foo = set()`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58441566), it works for me using an emty tuple, like so :

```
foo = {*()}
```